# connect PHP with GCM ON LIVE HOST

Tags: php, android

i am trying to connect my self to GCM by Live server. I am not using local host wamp server. I am doing it through live Host server. although i have connected GCM with my android mobile server, but i am getting this error of ERROR 401, my registration id is correct andy api key is also correct why can't i connect. plz help me with my code ..thank

```
<?php
if (mysql_connect("localhost", "devgol_gcm", "a2387as")) {

    mysql_select_db('devgol_gcm');

    $message = 'Testing message';

    $sender_id = $_REQUEST['sender_id'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO gcm set sender_id = " . $sender_id . ", message = '" . $message . "'";

    if ($query = mysql_query($sql)) {
        echo "records";

    } else {
        die(mysql_error());
    }

} else {
    echo "Connection failed";
}
$sender_ids = '379063187311';

$api_key = "AIzaSyDAYEiYfvLlndlG2pHox3O7BThkijtwinU";
$url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
$fields = array(
    'registration_ids' => $sender_ids,
    'data' => $message,
);
$headers = array(
    'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);
$ch = curl_init();

// Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));


$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ($result === FALSE) {
    die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
}

curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mistake in your code, you must use array for values in your $fields :

```
 $fields = array(
    'registration_ids' => array($sender_ids),
    'data' => array($message),
);
```

And do not forget to handle the return to get errors and new registration_id if there are some

Comment: thank for the guidance...now it is working ...but error wasn't in this file, it was in my other php file...thankx